# Solution for $\int \frac{1}{1-we^w}dw$

Tags: calculus, integration, ordinary-differential-equations, exponential-function, approximation

I am looking for a solution or a method of approximation for :
 $$\int \frac{1}{1-we^w}dw$$ 
that came up while working on an ODE problem.

Got any suggestions?

**Note:** $w$ is also a one variable function

Thanks to anyone who can lend a hand

**Update**:

The original ODE is: $$xdw=(e^{-w}-w)dx$$

Comment: There is no solution in elementary functions. The methods of approximations will depend on the restrictions on the variable (for example if $|w|<1$ a series solution seems best)

Comment: What's the original ODE? Perhaps you made an error?

Comment: Updated the question with original ODE, thanks to both for taking a moment of your time to help me out

Comment: Kind of important, there is a constant solution, there is a real number $w_0$ with $e^{-w_0} = w_0.$  Solutions for first order ODE cannot cross, so there are solutions with $w > w_0$ and others with $w < w_0.$ You should expect some horizontal asymptotes at $w \rightarrow w_0,$ along with evident vertical asymptotes at $x \rightarrow 0$

Answer (score 0):

[How to find $\mathrm{\sum_{n=1}^\infty E_{n}(n)= \lim_{k\to\infty}\int_1^\infty \frac{e^{kt+t}t^k-e^t}{e^{kt+2t}t^{k+1}-e^{kt+t}t^k}dt=.26929…}$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4201088/how-to-find-mathrm-sum-n-1-infty-e-nn-lim-k-to-infty-int-1-infty)  shows a nice result from your integral which will be generalized here using [geometric series](https://m.youtube.com/watch?v=Ux7vl6zXxj0) and [**gamma type functions**](https://functions.wolfram.com/GammaBetaErf/). The result is simple, but has the restriction of x<Ω=W(1) which is the [Omega constant](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Omega_constant):

$$\int \frac{dx}{1-xe^x}=-\int \sum_{n=0}^\infty \left(xe^x\right)^ndx=-\sum_{n=0}^\infty \int x^n e^{xn}dx$$

This is a close definition of the gamma function and exponential integral function mentioned in the bolded link:

$$\sum_{n=0}^\infty \int x^n e^{xn}dx=C-\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{ (e^{-n x} (e^x x)^n (-n x)^{-n} Γ(n + 1, -n x))}{n}\mathop=^{x\in\Bbb R} C-\sum_{n=0}^\infty x^{n+1} \text E_{-n}(-n x)=C+\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{(-1)^nΓ(1 + n, -n x)}{ n^{n+1}} $$

If there was some function, like a [**hypergeometric function**](https://functions.wolfram.com/HypergeometricFunctions/) to give a closed form, please post it. Please correct me and give me feedback!

Comment: Note the formula may work outside the restriction.