# How to find $\mathrm{\sum_{n=1}^\infty E_{n}(n)= \lim_{k\to\infty}\int_1^\infty \frac{e^{kt+t}t^k-e^t}{e^{kt+2t}t^{k+1}-e^{kt+t}t^k}dt=.26929…}$?

Tags: integration, sequences-and-series, improper-integrals, special-functions, gamma-function

As seen from this

> [*previous question*](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4195180/finding-the-complex-number-sum-n-1-infty-%CE%93-n-n)

Equating the arguments of gamma type functions and inducing a transformation onto them often gives nice results. These results are usually hard to evaluate using non-trivial methods. Here is a [generalized exponential integral function](https://functions.wolfram.com/GammaBetaErf/ExpIntegralE/) version. Here is the series for it, although it was said to diverge for the [seemingly convergent series](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=sum+expintegrale%28x%2Cx%29+from+1+to+9999). [Incomplete gamma function](https://functions.wolfram.com/GammaBetaErf/Gamma2/) information:

$$\mathrm{S_E=\sum_{n=1}^\infty E_{n}(n)=\sum_{n=1}^\infty n^{n-1}Γ(1-n,n)=\sum_{n=1}^\infty n^{n-1} \int_n^\infty t^{-n}e^{-t}dt=\sum_{n=1}^\infty \ \int_1^\infty \frac{dt}{e^{nt}t^n} =\quad\lim_{k\to\infty}\int_1^\infty \frac{e^{kt+t}t^k-e^t}{e^{kt+2t}t^{k+1}-e^{kt+t}t^k}dt= 0.2692923…}$$

I will work on this more, but wonder if there is an integral representation or a way to evaluate the sum using any method or at least get rid of the limit. Here is [proof](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=sum+e%5E%28-n+t%29+t%5E%28-n%29+from+n%3D1+to+infinity) of the partial sums. Please do not just expand the summation and say that is the answer or some other related “trivial” evaluation, as I am looking for an “actual” answer. It can use any well know functions and does not need to be in closed form, but simplify as much as possible. How can I write S without using a sum? Please correct me and give me feedback!

Comment: You have produced a series of very interesting problems ! Thanks for that.

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici Thanks, I have additional ideas for similar questions. These are more for recreational mathematics.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$E_n(n)=\int_1^{\infty } e^{-n t} t^{-n} \, dt\tag{1}$$

$$\sum _{n=1}^{\infty } e^{-n t} t^{-n}=\frac{1}{t\ e^t-1}\tag{2}$$

$$S=\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty E_{n}(n)=\int\limits_1^\infty\frac{1}{t\ e^t-1}\,dt=0.269292\tag{3}$$

---

The result in (3) above was derived using numerical integration via the [Mathematica NIntegrate function](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/NIntegrate.html). Also see [Wolfram Alpha evaluation of the integral](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integrate%201%2F%28t%20E%5Et%20-1%29%20%7Bt%2C1%2CInfinity%7D).

Comment: @TymaGaidash I'm not sure, but it seems like I've run across this constant before in other contexts. I'll search through my Mathematica notebooks to see if I can find something. The gamma function version is harder since $\Gamma(n,n)=\int\limits_n^\infty e^{-t}\ t^{n-1} \, dt$ is more complicated and also only valid for $\Im(n)\neq 0\lor \Re(n)>0$.

Comment: @TymaGaidash While searching the Internet earlier today for the constant I had a feeling of "déjà vu" like I'd searched for it before, but I didn't find anything on the Internet or in my notebooks so I guess I was wrong.